# How do I turn a python program into an .egg file?

Tags: python, deployment, egg

How do I turn a python program into an .egg file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) is the software that creates [.egg files](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs). It's an extension of the [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-distutils.html) package in the standard library.

The process involves creating a `setup.py` file, then  `python setup.py bdist_egg` creates an .egg package.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you need to get an .egg package off a single .py file app, check this link: [EasyInstall - Packaging others projects as eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#packaging-others-projects-as-eggs).

Answer (score 0):

Python has its own package for creating distributions that is called distutils. However instead of using Python’s distutils’ setup function, we’re using setuptools’ setup. We’re also using setuptools’ find_packages function which will automatically look for any packages in the current directory and add them to the egg. To create said egg, you’ll need to run the following from the command line:

```
c:\Python34\python.exe setup.py bdist_egg
```

Comment: this will only work on windows. Possibly only in certain environments even then. Could you include some explanation on what is required in setup.py?